# JS UI librarary

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I am very often write menu like that:

[image]

User clicks on menu item and see div block for this item.

Well it's not hard to code but take some time and very boring.

Is there any JS library which can make my life a little easy and automate writing typical UI elements?

Comment: There are many, many, many http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295123/what-is-a-good-very-high-level-ui-framework-for-javascript ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269372/html5-ui-framework

Comment: KnockoutJS is good when i am coding UI with many dependens. Not in my case. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you need is very similar to the one provided by jQuery UI tabs. Take a look at the demo [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).