# Javascript/CSS frameworks

Tags: javascript, css

Are there any JavaScript/CSS frameworks available to achieve following:

1. Customization of different UI items like popup windows, floating windows, dialog, sheet
2. Animations on images, moving an image, slide show of images
3. Event handlers, like mouse drag event on images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for me is the best candidate for what you're looking for.

Comment: Agreed.  There's a bit of a sharp learning curve getting started, but it really does make things easier.

Comment: Luckily, the documentation is plentiful and support is available, so once you pass that learning curve everything else is a breeze.

Comment: jQuery is not _the best_ candidate for what you're looking for, it's just one of the possibilities. It is the most popular, but there are other options out there. Sadly it's getting to the stage where for a lot of people jQuery _is_ javascript

Comment: I suggest it against other frameworks because of the amount of information there is out there to support it. Documentation, support for older browsers, plugins, usability and such and such are (to me) next to non. But you're right, there might be other frameworks out there better suited for this job, but are they as easy and flexible and well tested/documented as jQuery UI? I guess that all depends on the developer.

Comment: @fritzfromlondon out of curiosity, what would you suggest?

Comment: @AndresIlich I would do what I did in my answer below, i.e. give a list of the 4/5 more popular framework and say "here's a bunch,  they are all as good as each other (ish) have a read and pick the one you like the most".

Comment: Right, let OP decide for himself, but personally, what would you suggest? (as in, "the" one).

Comment: I like MooTools the most, but happy with jQuery Dojo too

Answer (score 3):

You can see and choose from this list http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/17/15-javascript-web-ui-libraries-frameworks-and-libraries/

And see this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255247/84201

Answer (score 2):

jQuery and jQuery UI are perfect for this: http://www.jquery.com and http://www.jqueryui.com should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well pretty much every JS framework does that - from ye olde Prototype.js / script.aculo.us / Livepipe (if you must), to jQuery / jQuery Tools (or jQuery UI - if you must), MooTools / MochaUI, Dojo / Dijit, YUI (if you must - but *never* with AlloyUI), ExtJS / Sencha.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with both jQueryUI and ExtJs and in my view, ExtJs is much better for aims you described. Yes, it is not free, but it definitely worth its cost. jQuery is great little framework, and it really shines when it comes to DOM manipulation, easy effects and event handling. ExtJs is first of all the richest set of components. And is so easy to build complex applications from these components.

Check extjs demos, and you will get what I mean:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/