# Javascript open source to make gui like chat application?

Tags: chat

Can anyone explain to me ? I want develop chat application with javascript ui.. I know jquery ui, yui, but I need more powerful to develop rich ui..

thanks,

Comment: probably you should have a look at this thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295123/what-is-a-good-very-high-level-ui-framework-for-javascript

Answer (score 0):

There is already an open source chat app called [Jabbr](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR) that would be a good start.