# How can I avoid EXTjs with YUI-based alternatives to EditorGridPanel and ColumnTree?

Tags: javascript, extjs, yui, yui-datatable

There's some discussion at my work about using Jack Slocum's EXTjs library as an extension to YUI (already in use) for a project in development.  I'd like to help avoid a dependence on EXTjs's commercial licensing model if possible.

The primary two features desired from EXTjs are EditorGridPanel and ColumnTree.

As far as I can see, it looks like YUI since 2.6.0 has added EditorGridPanel functionality to their DataGrid.  Is there some major caveat to using YUI's built-in functionality?  Is there something still way slicker about EditorGridPanel?

As for ColumnTree... I don't see any easy YUI replacement for this feature set.  Is there something in YUI that does this that I'm not seeing?  Is there some other good option now that YUI is barely in use?

Is it best to just bite the bullet and pay for EXTjs (and deal with the commercial license dependence) for this kind of functionality?

Comment: Damn, crickets.  Anyone care to tell me why this question is getting so little love?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for ExtJS alternatives like you. I'm intended to develope a Web Based application using Frameworks to avoid wasting valuable time.

You were too close to find the right page, here it is:
[[What are alternatives to ExtJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200284/what-are-alternatives-to-extjs])

Read the above article first, then you may want to see this other links:

**BackBase**
[http://demo.backbase.com/explorer/]
[http://demo.backbase.com/layouts/]
[http://demo.backbase.com/layouts/layout7/index.html]

**jQuery**
[http://ui.jquery.com/home]

**qooxdoo**
[http://qooxdoo.org/]
[http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/]
[http://ui.jquery.com/themeroller/]

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

My employer recently went through a similar evaluation with regard to the EXT widget library.  Our criteria were slightly different in that we were looking for a widget library that would plug into GWT and provide a more polished widget set than those provided by the default GWT implementation.  After a month of evaluation, our team concluded that the EXT license fees are a small price to pay for the functionality gained.  Again, we're not using the raw javascript library, but we have been very pleased with GXT.  In my opinion the library is a bit under-documented but it does work solidly across different browsers.  One thing for sure, their editor grid is very slick.