# Equivalent for Dgrid/Store (Dojo toolkit) in Jquery/Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, backbone.js

I have come accross those [grids](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/35122722/Grid-OtherGrids) and was wondering if they were any new ones (or recommended ones). Same about stores, I believe backbone as collection for instance. I'm looking for something similar and simple like Dojo implements it.

Basically, I want to have a **JsonStore** and pass this store to a grid (populated **onDemand**, so while I scroll ajax call are made).

In dojo, it looks something like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",

    "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
    "dgrid/Keyboard", 
    "dgrid/Selection",
    "dgrid/extensions/ColumnHider",
    "dgrid/editor",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dojo/store/JsonRest",
    "dojo/store/Cache",
    "dojo/store/Observable"

], function(
    declare,
    Grid,
    Keyboard, 
    Selection,
    Hider,
    editor,
    Memory,
    JsonRest,
    Cache,
    Observable
){

    var contentStore = Observable(Cache(JsonRest({
                        target:/* my url */, 
                        idProperty: "id",
                    }), Memory()));

    return declare([Grid, Keyboard, Selection, Hider], {
    store: contentStore,
    columns: {
        /* labels/columns names */
    },
    loadingMessage: 'Loading data...',
    noDataMessage: 'No data found',
    getBeforePut: false


    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe "Stable" for each plugin on that list should tell you how new or old they are. Arguably jQuery plugins won't be of a comparable quality as the Dojo dgrid. See this answer for some explanation why:

[What happened to Dojo in 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450696/what-happened-to-dojo-in-2008)

So my advice would be to rather look for opinions on some specific plugins from that list, maybe those with "Stable" most up to date?

As an alternative have a look at ExtJS project. It's not strictly speaking a jQuery plugin but it allows for easy interoperability with jQuery:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS