# Transfer javascript variable to php on the same page without submitting

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, jquery

Hi I would like to  transfer my javascript variable to php, it is just like a real time transferring. The user input, which is entered in a text box, will be transferred to php script to check if it is in the database. Then, the output will be displayed in another textbox that is readonly.

Comment: you can't do this. javascript is client side, php is server side...you're basically looking for AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this. I hope it would be better if you can understand the difference between client-side(JavaScript) and server-side(PHP) script. There are a lot questions have been answered with the similar issues. Please google and you can find them with examples. Also refer [Client side vs server side basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407374/client-side-vs-server-side-basics).

[Difference Between Client Side & Server Side Programming](http://www.ehow.com/about_5377868_difference-side-server-side-programming.html)

Comment: <script>

jQuery.validator.addMethod("ordrNum",function(value,element)

 var isExist=false;

  $.ajax({

   type : "POST",

   async: false,

            data : "action=checkOrdrNum&id=0&orderno=" + value,
            url  : ajaxurl,
   dataType:"json",
            success: function (data) {
   //console.log(data["order_no"]);
      if (data["order_no"] >0) {
     isExist=true;
    } 
   }
  });
  //console.log(isExist);
  
  return isExist;//true;

 },"This order number does not exists");
 </script>
 <?php 
  echo $_POST['orderno'];
  
  ?>

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look into AJAX. It sounds scary as an acronym, but it's quite easy to use.

In your Javascript (using jQuery, and assuming you have a textbox with the id "searchbox":

```
$.get("search.php", {"term":$("#searchbox")}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

In your PHP file "search.php":

```
echo "Yay! " . $_GET['term'] . " Woo!";
```

If you run the javascript on the textbox's keyup event, it'll get data live. So if you typed: "Hello World" into the box, you'd get a stream of annoying messageboxes saying:

"Yay! H Woo!", "Yay! He Woo!", "Yay! Hel Woo!", "Yay! Hell Woo!"... "Yay! Hello World Woo!"

From there it's a matter of making the PHP code return something useful. For that look into JSON. From there, it's a matter of writing Javascript to do something with the new, useful information.

http://jquery.com/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://www.json.org/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: can i put the code: "$.get("search.php", {"term":$("#searchbox")}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
}"

to search.php?

Comment: and how to use keyup using the given sample you provide