# PHP case switch statement with variable set in drop-down

Tags: php

HI can someone tell me where I'm going wrong with this code. For some reason the variable `$BlogType;` isn't going through the Switch statement. This variable is set using a HTML drop-down and I have tested that its value changes accordingly with the user choice using the echo statement at the beginning of the code.

But It doesn't seem to be going past the first 'break;' in the statement, as the echo statement in the Switch code below isn't printed:

```
echo "<br /> value in case " . $BlogType;
echo "<br /> Blog " . $BlogType;  // OK, value changes with dropdown choice



function getParameter($param, $defaultValue) {
        if (array_key_exists($param, $_GET)) {
        $value=$_GET[$param];
        return isSet($value)?$value:$defaultValue;
        }
        return $defaultValue;
    }

    $BlogType = getParameter("blog_type", "defaultValue");
    $byDate = getParameter("by_date", "defaultValue");


$loopArr = array();
switch ($BlogType) {

    case 0:
        $loopArr = $all_posts;                                                  
        break;

    case 1: 
        $loopArr = $music_matters->posts;
        echo "<br /> value in case " . $BlogType;
        break;

    case 2:
        $loopArr = $staff_student_news->posts;
        break;

    case 3:
        $loopArr = $kbs_news_events->posts;
        break;

    default: 
        $loopArr = array();
}

?>


<?php foreach ($loopArr as $post): {
    {    // code here
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7407500/4916265

Comment: Try to do `switch (trim($BlogType))`, and you have not show all relevant code to help you more here.

Comment: You need to put brackets around things with more than one thing:             `case 1: { $loopArr = $music_matters->posts;
            echo "<br /> value in case " . $BlogType;
            }                
break;`

Comment: @EvanCarslake - Brackets are not needed in this case.

Comment: You need to show how you are generating your select element.

Comment: Where are you setting `$BlogType` ?

Comment: have added more code

Comment: most likely it is a switch/case nonstrict comparison issue

Comment: if you add "var_dump($BlogType);" on the line just before "$loopArr = array();", what does the output say?

Comment: hi ti says C:\wamp\www\applicant\views\index.php:82:string 'defaultValue' (length=12)

Comment: cast the `$BlogType` to integer

Comment: ..when the page first loads it says below. could that be the problem. C:\wamp\www\applicant\views\index.php:82:string '' (length=0)

Comment: In what way would you cast it?

Comment: still no sucess

Comment: for instance, the `"defaultValue" == 0` is `true`, but `"defaultValue" == "0"` is `false`