# Is there any javascript framework like extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, frameworks

I hope to find a Javascript UI framework
which is stable, free, fast, browser-cross(support IE8), rich UI.

Comment: Vanilla Javascript, HTML and CSS fits all your requirements.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200284/what-are-alternatives-to-extjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are lists of Javascript UI framework which is mentions below.
>
> [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/)
>
> [backbase.js](https://my.backbase.com/home)
>
> [zinoui.js](http://zinoui.com/)
>
> [also check the Comparison of Sencha ExtJS and AngularJS](http://www.techferry.com/articles/ExtJS-vs-AngularJS.html)

Comment: ZinoUI's widgets are very rudimentary. DataTable doesn't even support sorting.